# How to resize the UITabBarController in iOS?

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

I used `UITabBarController` in my iOS app.
As you know , that `UITabBarController's` size is fix the screen of below.
I want to resize that `UITabBarController` with some CGRect because i don't want to fix the screen size.

Is there anyway to do like that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update the size, by accessing tab bar frame -

```
CGRect tabBarFrame=self.tabBar.frame;

// Update the frame values
tabBarFrame.origin.y =;
tabBarFrame.origin.x =;
tabBarFrame.size.hieght =;
tabBarFrame.size.width =;
self.tabBar.frame = tabBarFrame;
```